# React How to pass route render props to nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using an npm package to handle my auth state. (`@react-firebase/auth`)

I can't add props to this component, but this is rendered between my route handler and the nested component as follow:

```
<Route
     path="/admin/:campaignId"
     render={({ match, history }) => (
     <FirebaseAuthConsumer > //-----Can't add props here.
     {({ isSignedIn, user, providerId }) => {
                 

     return isSignedIn ? (
      <CreateScreen
        match={match}//----How can I pass the props to here?
        history={history}
        editMode={true}
      />
          ) : (
               <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        );
     }}
     </FirebaseAuthConsumer>
)}></Route>
```

How can I pass the props from the `route render function` to the `CreateScreen`
?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have already should work. The `react-router` recommended way is to not try and use them as props at all, but use hooks like `useHistory` instead. Alternatively you can use the `withRouter` HOC to wrap class components and get at the route params via props that way.

Comment: So `useHistory` should do the magic at the CreateScreen component level right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.